# mce: hardware error cpu 0 machine check 0 bank 0. System just freezes, everything just stops including mouse on Linux Mint XFCE 20

Tags: linux-mint, linux-kernel, ssd, freeze

My system was working fine but after the changes in past two days I started getting this problem.

​

**The Changes I made:** I added a 2GB 800mgz RAM stick and replaced my old *HDD* with a new *SSD* two days ago and installed Linux on it. And yesterday there was a *kernel update* in the update manager.

​

**How problem started occurring:** After the update and 3 or 4 reboots, when I was installing wine through  terminal system freezed and I had to do hard reboot, then again when  wine was installed I was installing Docky from Ubuntu 18.04's repository it  again freezed.

​

The third and fourth time it freezed right after booting up when I launched firefox.

​

Fifth time it happened again while editing a post on linuxmint forum.

​

After some googled suggestions I did a `smartctl`. So can you tell me weather it's a *system error* or the *SSD's* broken.

​

**Here are** `smartctl`**'s results in the given :** [link](https://termbin.com/w3so)

​

I also did a check for **bad sectors** in the SSD on which the system is installed.

​

**So are the problems due to SSD or the kernel or something else is wrong?**

**Here are it's results:**

​

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for mihir:     
Disk /dev/sda: 223.58 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: WDC WDS240G2G0A-
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x662c6f2a

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 468860927 467808258 223.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 468860927 467808256 223.1G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST500LT012-9WS14
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb540dc3c

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 976771071 976769024 465.8G 83 Linux
```

​

```
$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda1 > badsectors.txt
Checking blocks 0 to 524287
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

​

```
$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda2 > badsectors.txt
Checking blocks 0 to 0
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

​

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda5 > badsectors.txt
Checking blocks 0 to 233904127
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution, I was missing some important details, while booting into Mint a small error message flashed some times for 1-2 seconds saying `mce: hardware error cpu 0 machine check 0 bank 0`.

This can happen due to some reasons:

1. CPU Overheating or a permanent CPU damage.
2. VRAM/RAM Error.

In my case it was because I placed RAMs of different frequencies, I wanted to upgrade my RAM and didn't knew of what frequency of RAM was pre-installed. I placed the new RAM of 800mgz in the second slot ad after some days I started getting this problem.

Other reason could be that the old RAM stick was damaged. So try replacing one or more RAM sticks.

I removed the old RAM stick and replaced it with another 800mgz one, now the system runs fine.

Hoped this answer helped, because there is very less info present about thsi topic on the internet.